# Возможно ли использование двойного тире?

Tags: тире, авторская-пунктуация, многоточие

Вопрос для меня архисложный. Прошу помощи профессионалов.

"— Я приехал тогда поговорить с ним, а не лезть в ваши отношения! Я хотел извиниться, что наговорил ему —

— Мог бы извиниться по телефону! — перебил В."

Тире в конце предложения автор обосновывает влиянием пунктуации английского языка (прецедент - у Набокова) и тем, что многоточие не выражает резкого прерывания речи одного персонажа другим. Все бы ничего, но меня смущают два тире, одно за другим. Допустим ли этот вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Я думаю, что возможны два вида **авторской пунктуации.** Во-первых, это пунктуация, которая не соответствует обычным правилам (авторское интонационное тире, например). Во вторых, это **ненормированная пунктуация**, когда знаки или сочетания знаков ставятся не по правилам, существующим для этих знаков.

2) В частности, это касается **тире у Набокова**, когда этому знаку приписывается несвойственное ему (придуманное, чисто авторское) значение. К примеру, у Набокова "два раза после тире стоит точка, семь раз - вопросительный знак, двадцать семь раз не следует никакого знака препинания".

https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/ob-odnom-fakte-avtorskoy-punktuatsii-v-romane-v-v-nabokova-lolita

3) Поэтому за ненормированную пунктуацию ответственность целиком несет только автор, здесь **нельзя говорить о допустимости такой пунктуации.**

4) Кстати,  в правилах ПАС указана возможность **сочетания многоточия с восклицательным или вопросительным знаком,** когда незаконченность фразы дополняется вопросительной или восклицательной  интонацией **(это знаки на месте первой точки**). Такое обозначение мог бы использовать Набоков в настоящее время вместо тире и вопросительного знака.

§ 154. При сочетании вопросительного или восклицательного знака с многоточием знаки эти ставятся на месте первой точки: — Ну, что они там?.. (Шукш.); — Сейчас зайдем к старику, так?.. (Шукш.); «Эх, елки зеленые!..» — горько подумал он (Шукш.).

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

5) По аналогии с этим правилом, **если автор всё-таки берет на себя смелость пользоваться ненормированной пунктуацией**, то вместо тире для обозначения прерванной фразы логичнее было бы использовать знак "тире на месте первой точки":

— Я приехал тогда поговорить с ним, а не лезть в ваши отношения! Я хотел извиниться, **что наговорил ему —..**

Comment: большое спасибо за Ваши комментарии, они всегда мне помогают. Я тоже опиралась на статью из Киберленинки о допустимости такой пунктуации как авторской, но у Набокова прямая речь заключена в кавычки, и случая с двумя тире я не нашла. Можно узнать расшифровку аббревиатуры ПАС (извините за дилетантский вопрос, найти в гугле не получилось)?

Comment: ПАС - это Полный академический  справочник под редакцией Лопатина.  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101   Есть еще справочник Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php Это два основных официальных источника, которыми можно пользоваться и на которые обычно даются ссылки.